# Controller method won't got parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net-core, fetch

I made a post ajax request to server side.
the request reached to the server but the recieved parameters are empty/null.

no idea why this is happening, the problem is probably in the server. tried many solutions but nothing changed.

I hope some of you can help me.

```
    fetch('Home/AddMovie', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {

            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            movie: data_object
        }),

    }).then(res => res.text())         
        .then(text => {

        })  

        .catch((error) => {

            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
    public void AddMovie(Movie movie)
    {
        var movies = new List<Movie>();
        var newJson = "";
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(JsonFilePath))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();

            movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(json);
            movies.Add(movie);
            newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movies, Formatting.Indented);

        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(JsonFilePath, newJson);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work out

```cs
public void AddMovie([FromBody] Movie movie) { }
```

**Edit:**

Remove JSON.stringify() Just assign the object itself

Comment: after removing JSON.Stringfy  -->    body: {data_object}.
movie parameter is null in the controller's action.